# react-router not firing on sub-route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

My application is using react v15 and react-router 2.5.2. The configuration is simple:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={ store }>
      <Router history={ browserHistory }>
        <Route path="/" component={ App }>
          <IndexRoute component={ Home } />
          <Route path="incidents" component={ IncidentsContainer } />
          <Route path="incident/:id" component={ IncidentContainer } />
          <Route path="*" component={ NotFound } />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  document.getElementById('dashboard')
);
```

Everything works fine as long as the navigation happens on different routes, so from `incidents` to `incident/:id` it's ok etc. If I try to navigate from `incident/1` to `incident/2` the url is changed by the component but the routing event is never fired, so actually nothing happens. This is the component that creates a link and that's not working.

```
 handleClick() {
    const { data } = this.props;

    // This is called, the url changes but nothing happens
    browserHistory.push('/incident/' + data.originIncidentId);
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;

    return (<span className="link" onClick={this.handleClick}>{data.originIncidentId}</span>);
  }
```

Any idea why the router doesn't fire for that particular sub-route, that otherwise works perfectly? Thank you.

Comment: Dont you have to make it a sub-route? `<Route path="incidents"....><Route path="incidents/:id"... /> </Route>`?

Comment: in IncidentContainer, check in componentDidUpdate -> console.log(this.props.params.id)

Comment: @Tikkes: it's a subroute already, the correct one is incident/:id (incidents is related to a different page)

Comment: @Ultro: added the console.log and it shows the correct id it should go do, also the address bar updates to the correct value but there's not transition to the route.

Comment: I'm fairly new to React and had a similar issue and I had to make sure that, in the container/component where I was retrieving data for my route that contains :id param, I did that in componentWillReceiveProps. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: is the render in `IncidentContainer` firing? if it is then the router is working but your data / store isn't test that plz

Comment: @bdc and John Ruddell thank you both, problem solved. I was on the impression that the component would have to be remounted when instead it was being updated, moving the code into the componentWillUpdate() solved the issue. Thank you again for point that out!